# The bottom of my iPhone won't accept touches. Can I fix that?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone (1st Gen) is no longer able to recognize when I touch it at the very bottom of the screen.  The only way this effects me is when I have the keyboard up I cant hit the 123, spacebar, or send.

Is there some way I can fix this?  I've tried restoring but that didn't do the trick.  Is this something that I can take in and have fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off to the Genius Bar with you. Though I'm willing to bet they'll probably just recommend you get a new phone.

Comment: I have a similar feeling..

Comment: I only say it because I had an iPod battery go bad once outside of the warranty and the price to replace it was almost as a new one. I was told that was pretty much Apple's strategy when it came to mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

Turns the phone upside down and hope that the app you are using supports that orientation :)

Answer (score 0):

They might do 1G [here](http://cupertinoiphone.com/Cupertino_iPhone_Repair/iPhone.html). Worked great when I busted my 3GS screen.